# Review Simple Python Class

Tags: python

I have a assignment to create a code that creates a class, two functions and a subclass: [image: The questions]

Which i have done here

```
class BankAccount:

def __init__(self, startBal):
  self.balance = startBal

def deposit(self, amt):
  self.balance = self.balance + amt

def withdraw(self, amt):
  if amt > self.balance:
    return ('"invalid transaction"')
  else:
    self.balance = self.balance - amt

class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):

def __init__(self, bal):
  super(MinimumAccountBalance, self).__init(bal)
```

But upon running, I get this error:

```
  {"finished": true, "success": [{"fullName": "test_balance", "passedSpecNumber": 1}, {"fullName": "test_deposit", "passedSpecNumber": 2}, {"fullName": "test_sub_class", "passedSpecNumber": 3}, {"fullName": "test_withdraw", "passedSpecNumber": 4}, {"fullName": "test_balance", "passedSpecNumber": 5}, {"fullName": "test_deposit", "passedSpecNumber": 6}, {"fullName": "test_sub_class", "passedSpecNumber": 7}, {"fullName": "test_withdraw", "passedSpecNumber": 8}], "passed": false, "started": true, "failures": [{"failedSpecNumber": 1, "fullName": "test_invalid_operation", "failedExpectations": [{"message": "Failure in line 47, in test_invalid_operation\n    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.withdraw(1000), \"invalid transaction\", msg='Invalid transaction')\nAssertionError: Invalid transaction\n"}]}, {"failedSpecNumber": 2, "fullName": "test_invalid_operation", "failedExpectations": [{"message": "Failure in line 23, in test_invalid_operation\n    self.assertEqual(self.my_account.withdraw(1000), \"invalid transaction\", msg='Invalid transaction')\nAssertionError: Invalid transaction\n"}]}], "specs": {"count": 10, "pendingCount": 0, "time": "0.000052"}}
  "invalid transaction"
  "invalid transaction"
```

[image: Error msg]

I read up on AssetionError so I tried 'Invalid Transaction' instead of "invalid transaction", no luck there too

But baffling me is that the program seems to run fine on my system IDE so i don't think this is a syntax error but i don't know what else it could be.

I need help figuring out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: That assertion is almost certainly looking for "Invalid transaction" without any quotes at all.

Comment: This seems like a very poorly designed assignment. `withdraw` should raise an exception, not return a string, in the event of an overdraft. And if exceptions haven't been introduced yet, then the assignment should limit itself to concepts that *have* been introduced.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in the code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AssertionError is occurring because you are comparing the string `'"invalid transaction"'` with the string `'invalid transaction'`.  The first character of the first string is `"`; the first character of the second string is `i`.

(Although I would have expected a syntax error to be raised, as escaping the quotes \"like this\" outside of a string is not valid, but the message from your IDE suggests something else is going on)

I agree with the other commenters -- it would make a lot more sense for your method `withdraw` to throw an exception if an invalid transaction occurs.  In your unit test, you can then assert that this exception is raised.

Here is what the method might look like:

```
def withdraw(self, amt):
    if amt > self.balance:
        raise ValueError('Invalid transaction')
    else:
        self.balance = self.balance - amt
```

Then in your unit test, if you are using unittest framework, you can use assertRaises to check that the method raises the exception when it should https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises